# The name of my toes

Tags: word-choice, names

Ok.. I broke some toes in my foot and I want to tell a friend about it on Facebook.

Now, here's the problem. Every foot has 5 toes. Only 3 toes have a name:

- big toe
- middle toe
- small toe

What's the name of the others?

Comment: This little piggie went to market, this little piggie stayed home, this little piggie had roast beef, ...

Comment: So the names are *market toe,* *home toe,* *roast beef toe,* *none toe,* and *wee toe*?

Comment: -1 and voting to close as general reference because the question shows no research and can be answered by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toe).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The toes are, from medial to lateral:

- [Hallux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallux) ("big toe" or "great toe"), the innermost (most proximal) toe and the closest to the toes of the other foot
- Second toe or "[long toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_toe)" (although commonly shorter than the big toe)
- Third toe, occasionally described as the "ring toe"
- Fourth toe, sometimes described as the "ring toe"
- [Fifth toe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_toe) ("little toe", "pinky toe", or "baby toe"), the outermost (most distal) toe

Comment: I wonder how many understand what I am talking about when I say that my hallux hurts.

Comment: If you were a monkey it would be the thumb toe.

Answer (score 9):

Looking on [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=first+toe%2C+second+toe%2C+third+toe%2C+fourth+toe%2C+fifth+toe%2C+little+toe%2C+pinky+toe%2C+ring+toe%2C+middle+toe&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), the names that are most used appear to be:

> Big toe,
>   Second toe,
>   Third toe  (or middle toe),
>   Fourth toe,
>   Little toe (or fifth toe).

I have left "big toe" out of the Ngram, because it dominates everything else.

Answer (score 6):

To continue your naming terminology (which are the common names anyway):

- Big toe
- Index toe
- Middle toe
- Ring toe
- Pinky toe

Answer (score 2):

There are medical technical terms for each of the toes, but in common parlance, **only two toes have names**, the **big toe** and **the pinky toe** (the smallest one).